# Why multiplying 1.0 to 5 gave output 5 and not 5.0?

Tags: c++, c++98

```
cout<<5*1.0<<endl;
cout<<(float)5<<endl;
```

In both cases I got 5 as an answer and not 5.0. Please help...

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the format and precision for floatingPoint output, such as:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << 5*1.0;
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/G361nU)

From [The.C++.Programming.Language.Special.Edition] 21.4.3 FloatingPoint Output [io.out.float]:

> Floatingpoint output is controlled by a format and a precision:
>
> – The
> general format lets the implementation choose a format that presents a
> value in the style that best preserves the value in the space
> available. The precision specifies the maximum number of digits. It
> corresponds to printf()’s %g (§21.8).
>
> – The scientific format presents
> a value with one digit before a decimal point and an exponent. The
> precision specifies the maximum number of digits after the decimal
> point. It corresponds to printf()’s %e .
>
> – The fixed format presents a
> value as an integer part followed by a decimal point and a fractional
> part. The precision specifies the maximum number of digits after the
> decimal point. It corresponds to printf()’s %f .